# Windows Unattended Installation - Unattended.xml AdministratorPassword Encryption / Hashing

Tags: windows, hash, passwords

I'm trying to figure out how i could manually (on a linux machiene) encrypt / hash the password in the Autounattended.xml for the AdministratorPassword.

Right now i have an hash from the Windows Tool generated like:

```
        <UserAccounts>
            <AdministratorPassword>
                <Value>eAB4AEgANwAtAEgASAAyAGYAQQBkAG8AaQBuAGkAcwB0AHIAYQB0AG8AcgAQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQA</Value>
                <PlainText>false</PlainText>
            </AdministratorPassword>
        </UserAccounts>
```

I would like to know how i have to hash a password in linux to put the hashed string into the Autounattended.xml for an automatic windows installation.

Right now i do not find any clues about how the password is hashed, and it seems for now i only can generate an hashed password via the Windows unattended generation tool..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash is a base64 representation of the actual password concatened with `AdministratorPassword` string. But I'm not absolutely sure because your hasn't exactly this string.

Comment: late answer - yes its just a simple base64 code with `AdministratorPassword` concatened... is there a way to set a secure password?